# dotnet build with several runtimes

Tags: .net, nuget

I want to create `nuget` package from `csproj`. The project is managed library that must be different for different runtimes. Also it it targeted for different frameworks. So I need to have 4 DLLs for 2 runtimes (`win`, `linux`) and 2 frameworks (`net451`, `netstandard2.0`).

Specifying `TargetFrameworks` node helps me to get package with subfolders for different frameworks.

I would expect that `RuntimeIdentifiers` help me. But it seems that it is ignored during build and pack.

Is it possible to create such package only by means `csproj` file and `dotnet` utility, without creation dedicated `nuspec` file and complex build script?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Good point. Question is added. Thank you.